# rsocket - RDMA socket API - client unable to connect to server

Tags: sockets, rdma, mellanox

I have written simple client & server program using rsocket - RDMA socket API using following version of librdmacm-dev & librdmacm1 package (using Ubuntu 14.04):

librdmacm1/trusty 1.0.16-1 i386
librdmacm-dev/trusty 1.0.16-1 i386

1. When server is started, it fails in rselect() call, with following error:

   `$ ./rserver 192.168.1.1 8000
    rselect: Cannot allocate memory`
2. Instead of rsocket APIs used Unix Socket APIs and tried to run server by LD_PRELOADing of "/usr/lib/rsocket/librspreload.so", but it failed with same error:

   `$ export LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/rsocket/librspreload.so; ./rserver 192.168.1.1 8000
   rselect: Cannot allocate memory`

I didn't find any good online help on rsockets nor found any sample working code? 
Can some one help on resolving this?

Answer (score 1):

My colleague saw the same problem while fiddling with rdma using rsocket preload. In his case it turned out to be a rights issue.
Try running as root and see if that gets you any further.